# Extract PDF coordinates using mouse click

Tags: pdf, itext, mouse-coordinates

I want to extract the coordinates of a PDF document with the help of a mouse click. I have gone through some posts but since I'm new to this, I'm not being able to understand it properly. Also, can this be done if I render the PDF file in a web page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript to a pdf document. Although you only get access to a limited subset of the language.

If you only need the coordinates once (for instance when doing layout of the document), you can simply open it with adobe and activate the rulers/grid option to see where your mousepointer is currently located.